# Making react native touches respond faster

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to build a custom keyboard in react native, and I am using Pressable as a button component. Everything is working fine, but the responsiveness of buttons is a little slow when I quickly press multiple buttons.

For-example, if I quickly press 1,2 and 3 on the custom keyboard component, the onPress is only triggered for 1 and 3 and not for 2. This depends on the speed by which I touch the buttons, if I wait maybe half a second between each press it would register all touches in this case 1, 2 and 3.

I also tested this in a blank project with only two buttons, if you quickly touch both buttons, one after the other only the first onPress is called.

Is there a better way of registering touches quickly? Or any solution to implement a custom keyboard in react native.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [TouchableOpacity](https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchableopacity) instead